# how to show sleep Analysis data in Health kit app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, healthkit

I have a HealthKit object with all the proper setup, and I am trying to write to the Sleep Analysis data area of HealthKit, however I cannot find out that type in `HKCategoryTypeSleepAnalysis`.
 The `HKCategoryTypeSleepAnalysis` has some sub items (i.e  `HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisInBed`, `HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleep`) . This is my code:

```
- (void)readDailyStepsSince:(NSDate *)date completion:(void (^)(NSArray *results, NSError *error))completion {

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];

    comps.hour = 0;

    comps.minute = 0;

    comps.second = 0;

    NSDate *midnightOfStartDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSDate *anchorDate = midnightOfStartDate;

    HKQuantityType *stepType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];

    HKStatisticsOptions sumOptions = HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum;

    NSPredicate *dateRangePred = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:midnightOfStartDate endDate:today options:HKQueryOptionNone];

    NSDateComponents *interval = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    interval.day = 1;

    HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query = [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:stepType quantitySamplePredicate:dateRangePred options:sumOptions anchorDate:anchorDate intervalComponents:interval];

    query.initialResultsHandler = ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *result, NSError *error) {

        NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (HKStatistics *sample in result.statistics) {

            double steps = [sample.sumQuantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit countUnit]];

            NSDictionary *dict = @{@"date": sample.startDate, @"steps": @(steps)};

            [output addObject:dict];

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (completion != nil) {

                NSLog(@"[STEP] %@", output);

                completion(output, error);

            }

        });

    };

    [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];

}
```

My doubt is how to show the details in Sleep Analysis in the Health app. Actually the values are not showed in sleep analysis.

Comment: You seem insistent on implementing HealthKit functionality without actually reading the documentation.  That isn't the way to do it.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for your response. will u guide me.. plz

Comment: No.  This is my point.  You don't want to learn you just want to get your app integrated with HealthKit without reading a single page of documentation.